# Is asking too many questions in comments bad thing here

Tags: discussion

When I ask a question, I keep asking doubts in comments even when there are multiple answers. Sometimes comments lead to chat. I feel I ask too many doubts. However, I feel the quality of my comments is improved from past. Earlier I would ask basic questions that could be *Googled*, but now what I mostly ask isn't easily available or I can't find easily.

Is it bad behavior from me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Keep at it.

Asking questions is what this site is for. Especially if your own research falls short. If an answer is not clear enough to you, comments are the right place to ask for clarification. Don't hesitate to ask follow-up questions there. If more than a certain number of comments are under the same post, at some point it will be converted to a chat. That is more than okay.

One exception would be when you get off-topic in your comment thread and your question for clarification becomes a valid new main-site question in its own right. In that case, post it as such, preferably linking back to the original question and answer.

Lastly, do realise that it might be that answerers may not have time or opportunity to answer a follow-up question right away. This site runs on volunteers, who also have a day job to do. Be patient with them. :)

Comment: I have been meaning to answer this, but time was fleeting this week. There is nothing I have to add to this answer. Thank you Vincent.